# Implementing Quicksort Partition Algorithm with first element as pivot

Tags: algorithm

I am trying to implement Quick sort partition Algorithm with first element as pivot,  I have studied Quicksort with last element as pivot . Can someone please tell me where I am wrong in the following pseudocode ?

```
/* Taking first element of array as pivot and movig all elements 
smaller than pivot left to pivot and greater tto its right */
// L is leftmost index, R is rightmost index 

Partition(A[],L,R) 
{
    pivot = A[L]
    i = L-1
    for (j =L to R )
    {
        // If current element is smaller than or equal to pivot

        if (A[j] <= pivot)
        {
            i++;    // increment index of smaller element
            swap A[i] and A[j]
        }
    }
    swap A[i + 1] and A[L])
    return (i + 1)
}
```

Comment: quicksort is in C++. Qsort is the quicksort equivalent in C.

Comment: Are you *sure* you're wrong? What makes you think that? And have you tried explaining the pseudo-code to your [rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging)?

Comment: if you know the correct code for pivot with last element then one thing you can do is that swap the first and last element and run the code for pivot with last element. Little effort is required in that.

Comment: Why are you assigning i to L - 1 if L is the left-most index?  Also, j can start at L+1, otherwise you swap the pivot with itself.  Part of quicksort also involves quicksorting the left and right sides, otherwise you've only placed items less than the pivot to the left and items greater than the pivot to the right.

Comment: @narusin, he's clearly talking about the Quicksort *algorithm*, not any particular implementation in one language's or another's standard library.

Comment: One of the great things about pseudocode is that you can use it to write *real* code.  Then you can compile and run that real code to see whether it works, and run it in a debugger when it turns out not to work.

Comment: The fact that you come to us with *pseudocode* that you seem confident is wrong tells me that someone else has already evaluated it and instructed you to fix it.  We are open to helping with homework, but we do prefer that you tell us when that's what you're presenting.  And we generally avoid giving you homework answers outright, as in the long run, that doesn't help anyone.

Comment: @Neil thanks , I worked on those lines and it worked .

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude your rubber duck thing is a nice approach  , thanks for sharing .

Comment: @JohnBollinger Its not for homework , I am trying beginner challanges in hackerrank.

Answer (score 1):

@SiggiSv
**Based on your answer, it is needed to increment 'R' by 1 so the last element of the array is sorted too with the array and not left out following your code**

```
Partition(A[],L,R) 
{
    pivot = A[L]
    i = L
    for (j =L+1 to R+1 )
    {
        if (A[j] <= pivot)
        {
            i++;    // increment index of smaller element
            swap A[i] and A[j]
        }
    }
    swap A[i] and A[L])
    return (i)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After some trial and error and a lot of pondering I found my mistake . Here's the correct algorithm .

```
Partition(A[],L,R) 
{
    pivot = A[L]
    i = L
    for (j =L+1 to R )
    {
        if (A[j] <= pivot)
        {
            i++;    // increment index of smaller element
            swap A[i] and A[j]
        }
    }
    swap A[i] and A[L])
    return (i)
}
```

Comment: With this algorithm the array `[3,-1,1,5,4]` would become `[1,-1,3,5,4]`.  You need to continue the algorithm for the left side and the right side.

Comment: That's what happens in a Quicksort, @Neil, but the OP specifies (and documents in the question) that he is writing pseudocode for the partitioning part alone.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick summary of how the "Partition Algorithm" works:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MLpH7mpwOxQ

The goal of the partition algorithm is to simply take some collection of elements (for example, you work with “arrays”) and then partitioning (or splitting!) this collection around the pivot into two parts — left part and right part.

There should be some "rule" regarding the elements on the left of the pivot and on the right of the pivot. For example, all elements on the left will be smaller than the chosen pivot and all the elements on the right will be greater than the pivot.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

This is my version of Partition used in Quick Sort.
Also works with arrays, containing duplicates.
Partition places pivot, which is always first element, at its place in sorted array. Assume left and right pivot's sub arrays are sorted, job's done.

```
int partition(int arr[],int p, int q) {
    int i = p;
    int j = q;
    int pivot = arr[p]; //choose pivot to be a first element
    while (i < j) {
        for (; arr[i] < pivot; i++); //iterate from the beginning till an element is larger or equals to pivot
        for (; arr[j] > pivot; j--); //iterate from the end till an element is less or equals to pivot

        if(i < j) {                 //if both for loops are done, arr[i] >= pivot and needs to be
                                    //on pivot's left. arr[j] <= pivot, so we throw it to pivot's right
            if(arr[i] == arr[j])
                i++;    //taking care of duplicates

            swap(arr[i], arr[j]);
        }
    }
    cout << j<<endl;            //now pivot is in its place as if array was sorted
    return j; //all elements on j's left are smaller than all elements on j's right
}

void quicksort(int arr[], int p, int r)
{
    if (p > r ) {
        return;
    }
    int q = partition(arr, p,  r);
    quicksort(arr, p, q-1); 
    quicksort(arr, q+1, r);
}
```